# how to fix that error in python2.7"TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

I am a beginner in machine learning python, I set that code and it was working perfectly fine but when I run this part of code `plt.plot(X_train,Y_train, color = 'red')` it gives me the error:

> `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

**Code:**

```
#splitting data
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test= train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, 
random_state=0)

#fitting simple linear regression to the training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train,Y_train)
#predicting the test set results
Y_pred=regressor.predict(X_test)

#plotting the training set
plt.plot(X_train,Y_train, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train,regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('exp vs salary(training set)')
plt.xlabel('exp')
plt.ylabel('salary')
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you post full error traceback?

Comment: check the type of X_train and Y_train

Answer (score 0):

We cannot say anything concrete unless we see the full trace-back. But, it seems like there is a problem with your matplotlib.pyplot function. Try importing it once again or updating it in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

try : plt.scatter(X_train, Y_train, color = 'red')